# Insert a chain in a file at a specific point

Tags: php, string, file, replace

I want to insert a chain in a file at a specific point in php.

Here's an example (what i try):

```
$insert = "Example of Chain";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
//Example of content: codecodecode <tag> EXAMPLE EXAMPLE </tag> code code code
//Result i need  = codecodecode Example of Chain codecodecode
```

So as you can see, i need to remove the content of the tags and their nodeValue and replace it by the `$insert`. Also, please noticed that i need to use file_get_contents.

Thanks for your advice and tricks

Here's a try. This code spot the tags in a file content (by file_get_contents) and replace the code by a text return from a function `retrieveLinks` BUT i dont know how to put back the text in the file at the RIGHT position:

//It doesnt appear if its between '' so i put it volontary like that .. not a mistake

> $start = 'tag'; 
>        $end = '/tag';

```
 $startChain = strpos($fileContent, $start);
 $endChain = strpos($fileContent, $end) + strlen($end);

 $text = substr($fileContent, $startChain, $endChain - $startChain);

 require_once("showISComment.php");
 $newText = retrieveLinks($project);

 $content = str_replace($text, $newText, file_get_contents($file));


 //file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

Comment: But you did not try anything. To replace something in a text you can always use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)

Comment: I already did .. ill put the code in the question.

Comment: If you know the tag then how about using str_replace function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the content of the tag then this would do it

```
file_put_contents(
    $file,
    str_replace(
        '<tag> EXAMPLE EXAMPLE </tag>',
        $insert,
        file_get_contents($file)
    )
);
```

Comment: And it will be replace in the file AND saved?

Comment: Yes it will `file_put_contents` saves the file